# Ensuring Matrix is symmetric (and positive-semidefinite)

Tags: matlab, matrix, covariance

I am currently implementing an online estimation algorithm for a set of covariance matrices and due to numerical errors, my covariance matrices happen to be not symmetric at all times.

I currently resolve this by mirroring the upper triangular matrix onto the lower one:

```
    for i=1:T
       tempSigma(:, :, i) = eye(D)/sigmaT(:,:,i);
       temp = triu(tempSigma(:,:,i), 1);
       tempSigma(:, :, i) = triu(tempSigma(:, :, i));
       tempSigma(:, :, i) = tempSigma(:, :, i) + temp';
    end
```

Looping over every single matrix becomes very slow for large *T*s. Is there any way to speed this up in Matlab?

Comment: How big are the dimensions? How slow?

Comment: Does enforcing symmetry guarantees positive semi-definiteness?

Comment: No, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have an NxNxT array, where each plane of the matrix is to be considered a covariance matrix?

Learn to use MATLAB as it was designed to be used. Try to avoid explicit loops. For example, this will simply average the upper and lower triangles:

```
tempSigma = (tempSigma + permute(tempSigma,[2 1 3]))/2;
```

It is a logical way to solve the problem, arguably better than throwing away the lower triangle completely. And it runs in one line of code, with no explicit loops.